# How to enable Firebase SMS Authentication in MacOS - Flutter

Tags: macos, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter project, SMS auth is working on the web and Android (yet to test on IOS). When testing on Mac (physical device) I get this error:

UnimplementedError (UnimplementedError: RecaptchaVerifier is not implemented)

I am unable to find documentation on how to make SMS auth work on MacOS. If this is not possible, what suggestions do you have where I can still use Google's SMS Auth on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Firebase Authentication currently only supports phone number verification on mobile clients (iOS, Android and Web). It does not currently support phone number verification on macOS.

Comment: So, would you know of a via-media, process or alternative, while still using Google's SMS auth? For example, should I think of launching a browser etc?